# Python 2.7 : how to extract from between special characters

Tags: python, string, extract

I have a string like this :

```
'|||stuff||things|||others||||'
```

Is there a simple way to extract all the content contained between | characters, so the end result would be something like:

```
result = ['stuff', 'things', 'others']
```

edit: I would not know the content of the string in advance, as in i do not know specifically to look for 'stuff', 'things', or 'others', I just know that whatever is between the | characters needs to saved as its own separate string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i for i in string.split('|') if i!='']
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on one or more `|` with `re.split`:

```
re.split(r'\|+', str_)
```

This will give empty strings at start and end, to get rid of those use a list comprehension to take only the strings that are *truthy*:

```
[i for i in re.split(r'\|+', str_) if i]
```

**Example:**

```
In [193]: str_ = '|||stuff||things|||others||||'

In [194]: re.split(r'\|+', str_)
Out[194]: ['', 'stuff', 'things', 'others', '']

In [195]: [i for i in re.split(r'\|+', str_) if i]
Out[195]: ['stuff', 'things', 'others']
```